# Set-AzureVnetConfig and New-AzureService in specific resource group

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

The 2 commands

```
Set-AzureVnetConfig -ConfigurationPath $VNetCfgPath
New-AzureService -ServiceName $CloudServiceClassicName -AffinityGroup $AffinityGroup
```

create their own resource groups but I want them to create resource in a specific resource group already existing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Those cmdlets are from the Classic deployment model for Azure and thus do not understand the concept of a resource group.

Resource Manager Supported Services:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services

Azure Resource Manager vs. classic deployment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model

You should be able to move the new resources after the fact using Resource Manager cmdlets like `Move-AzureResourceGroup`. Going forward, I would recommend looking at migrating your resources over to the Azure Resource Manager deployment model unless you have a specific requirement tying you to the Classic model.